# "Personal Payment" Button in Paypal?

Tags: paypal

Our website needs to facilitate a Paypal "personal payment" from one user to another. This is a gift (i.e. a birthday present), and **not** a payment for product/services, nor is it a charity donation.

Personal payments can be easily made from the Paypal control panel (crucially without a fee if not using a credit card). However, I cannot find a way to implement a simple html button that launches a personal payment instead of a commercial payment.

Is anyone aware of a solution, other than telling the user to log into Paypal and complete the payment (which is a clunky solution that we'd rather avoid!). I would like to prepopulate the amount and Paypal address that will be receiving the payment etc, exactly like the normal "Pay" button, but as a personal payment, not a commercial payment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro), specifically the [Pay API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation) with the PAYMENTTYPE set to PERSONAL in your request.

Comment: I'm a very similar situation to the OP.
The docs you linked say that to use paytmenttype PERSONAL you have to set feesPayer to EACHRECEIVER or SENDER.  This implies to me that there are still fees, but the reason I want to use the PERSONAL payment type is so the transaction can be fee-less.  Do you know if there are fees charged when using this?

Comment: If you set personal and cash funds are used (paypal or bank funds) then there will be no fee.  If a credit card is used as the funding source then there would be.

Comment: i thought the fee in that refered to when you are getting money from overseas

Comment: I'm going down this route and it seems the app needs reviewing first. That's ok, but if you are in a hurry it's a problem. Best not to send wedding invites out whilst finishing off the registry page.... :X

Comment: Unless you're doing something unique, most of the apps get immediately approved, but yes, I would always recommend getting through that before making any important plans.